# Duplicate entry on the database while using datagrid and utilizing triggered event

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

Can I somehow disable the Datagrids ability to invoke Add and Save methods on the binded database, in this case Entity Framework? I'm getting duplicate and I assume its initiated by the datagrid itself.

I'm using datagrid to add new element via its `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs` trigger. By using Mvvm Lights generic `RelayCommand` on `viewModel` I'm triggering this method:

```
private void DataGridRowEditEndingExecute(DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var device = new Device();
    var newDevice = e.Row.DataContext as Device;
    if (_isInsertMode)
    {
        if (newDevice != null)
        {
            var insertRecord = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add " + newDevice.Name + " as a new device?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (insertRecord == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                device.DeviceId = 0;
                device.Name = newDevice.Name;
                device.Supplier = newDevice.Supplier;
                device.Category = newDevice.Category;
                device.Description = newDevice.Description;
                device.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Devices.AddDevice(device);
                _context.Devices.Load();
                _context.Complete();
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => DeviceCollection);
                MessageBox.Show(device.Name + " has being added!", "Inserting Record", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Devices.Load();
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => DeviceCollection);
            }
            _context.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

The `_context.Complete();` always saves two sets of the entity into database. One with the correct timestamp and one without it. After this the following last `_context.Complete()` call removes the one without the timestamp?

Here's the datagrid xaml:

```
<DataGrid 
                  x:Name="DeviceListDataGrid" 
                  Margin="0,25,0,0"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
                  AlternationCount="2" 
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DeviceCollection}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkCyan"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkCyan"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceIdentification" Header="Id" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding DeviceId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceName" Header="Name" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceDescriptionColumn" Header="Description" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceSupplier" Header="Supplier" Width="150*" Binding="{Binding Supplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceCategory" Header="Category" Width="150*" Binding="{Binding Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                    <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DataGridRowEditEndingCommand}"/> 
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                    <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DataGridPreviewKeyDownCommand}"/> 
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddingNewItem">
                    <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DataGridAddingNewItemCommand}"/> 
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="BeginningEdit">
                    <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DataGridBeginningEditCommand}"/> 
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGrid>
```

and the datagrid is binded into this ICollectionView (maybe not the most correct approach?)

```
public ICollectionView DeviceCollection
{
    get
    {
        _context.Devices.Load();
        _deviceCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_context.Devices.GetLocal());
        return _deviceCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_deviceCollection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _deviceCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DeviceCollection");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is type of `DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DeviceCollection`? Is it `ObservableCollection<DeviceCollection>`?

Comment: It is the `ICollectionView` described above, where `_deviceCollection` is `ICollectionView`, also `GetLocal` is returning an  `ObservableCollection<TEntity>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you trigger `DataGridRowEditEndingExecute` function then add item here. In your `ObservableCollection` (say it name `o`) have this event: `o.CollectionChanged += o_CollectionChanged;`. You should use this instead, don't add item manually.

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

bool isAddedbyApp = false;
void o_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) // User add new item
    {
        foreach(var item in e.NewItems)
        {
            if (!isAddedbyApp)
            {
                var entity = item as Device; // or your Model
                // Do some thing here: ask user, ..., validate value
                // If you don't want this item, you call call remove function to remove it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also have check if items is added by your app or user before process it.

When an item is added by your app (not by user) set `isAddedbyApp = true;`. When finished, set `isAddedbyApp = false;`

Comment: hmm, ok. Where is this event best located? `GetLocal()`is accessing entity framework `_context`.

Comment: I followed with my earlier solution this [guide](https://gsselle.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/wpf-datagrid-update-insert-and-delete-operations/)

Comment: @ajr that guide don't bind data directly, after user insert a row, it have to rebind (you can see it call `dgEmp.ItemsSource = GetEmployeeList();`, which recreate a collection every time user add row, which is shouldn't). For you question, You can locate it anywhere you want, ussually inside your view model or where you declare your `ObservableCollection`, as it don't involve anything with the UI (Don't have to care what datagrid/listbox make this event). Only remember that if user say `No` with your messagebox then you remove that new item from collection.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tips! One additional question, where should I place the actual `_context.Completed()` function? This actually calls the entity framework `saveChanges()` method.

Comment: It depend on when and where you call it. If you call it after use click "Yes", it can put same place with `CollectionChanged`. Then you can pass `e.NewItems` to it.

Comment: I am not allowed to use `MessageBox`inside the `foreach`loop, I think? Also the event `Device_CollectionChanged` fires right away after I click the cell on dataGrid? This results as a null entity inside the `foreach`.

Comment: It is allowed, even your function is executed at background thread. And no, it fires after user finish add row to collection (ie: press Enter or click to other rows/controls. Exactly, it happen after a row is added and before a new blank/default row is created automaticly by window). If you received a null item, it is most likely this item is add somewhere by your app (not user) and you don't add a filter (like me do above) for this action.

Comment: Ok I seem to be doing something quite wrong, I created [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766369/how-to-correctly-handle-the-collectionchanged-event-of-datagrid) and I would appreciate if you could take a quick look of it. I'm sure its quite obvious mistake.

Comment: @ajr Ok. I'll look at it