# How to correctly handle the CollectionChanged event of datagrid?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection, collectionview

I initially asked a question related to dataGrid insert/delete/save operations with Entity Framework [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722363/duplicate-entry-on-the-database-while-using-datagrid-and-utilizing-triggered-eve) However I was not able to totally get the suggested approach to work. Here's my approach so far:

**ViewModel constructor**

```
public DeviceDatabaseViewModel()
{
    LoadData();
}
```

**LoadData**

```
private void LoadData()
{
    _context.Devices.Load();
    _devices = _context.Devices.GetLocal();

    _devices.CollectionChanged += Device_CollectionChanged;

    DeviceCollectionView = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = _devices }.View;
}
```

**Event**

```
private bool _isAddedbyApp = false;

private void Device_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var device = new Device();
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var entity = item as Device;
                if (entity == null) continue;
                if (_isAddedbyApp) continue;

                _isAddedbyApp = true;
                _context.Devices.Add(entity);
                _isAddedbyApp = false;
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                var entity = item as Device;
                if (entity == null) continue;
                if (_isAddedbyApp) continue;

                _isAddedbyApp = true;
                _context.Devices.Remove(entity);
                _isAddedbyApp = false;
            }
            break;
        //Reset = Clear
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:

            break;
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<DataGrid 
          x:Name="DeviceListDataGrid" 
          Margin="0,25,0,0"
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" 
          AlternationCount="2" 
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.DeviceCollectionView}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel.SelectedDevice}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkCyan"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DarkCyan"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceIdentification" Header="Id" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding DeviceId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceName" Header="Name" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceDescriptionColumn" Header="Description" Width="200*" Binding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceSupplier" Header="Supplier" Width="150*" Binding="{Binding Supplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DeviceCategory" Header="Category" Width="150*" Binding="{Binding Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `GetLocal`returns `ObservableCollection` from the Entity Framework database which also is implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

However I'm unable to find the correct place for the `SaveChanges` method of Entity Framework, and additionally the structure seems to be a bit off?

**EDIT**

If I have placed the `SaveChanges` at the end of the event `CollectionChanged` my program hangs. Actually I had for some Debug reasons a MessageBox inside the `SaveChanges()` method, after disabling it things seems to be more or less in the right direction..

**EDIT 2**
Adding the Device entity definitions. 
[Link to the file](https://github.com/ajr85/FxTesting/blob/master/FxEditorDatabaseStructure/Core/Domain/Device.cs), because its rather long..

MessageBox is resulting with this **exception**:

> {"An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.\n  See the
>   inner exception for more information."}
>
> {"Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read
>   this):\r\nThis exception was thrown because the generator for control
>   'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:28' with name
>   'DeviceListDataGrid' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events
>   that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The
>   following differences were detected:\r\n  Accumulated count 27 is
>   different from actual count 28.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last
>   Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]\r\n  At index 26: 
>   Generator's item '{NewItemPlaceholder}' is different from actual item
>   'FxEditorDatabaseStructure.Core.Domain.Device'.\r\n\r\nOne or more of
>   the following sources may have raised the wrong events:\r\n
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator\r\n
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection\r\n
>   System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView\r\n
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[FxEditorDatabaseStructure.Core.Domain.Device,
>   FxEditorDatabaseStructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]\r\n(The starred sources are considered more
>   likely to be the cause of the problem.)\r\n\r\nThe most common causes
>   are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a
>   corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index
>   or item parameter.\r\n\r\nThe exception's stack trace describes how
>   the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a
>   more timely exception, set the attached property
>   'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High'
>   and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command
>   similar to the following:\n
>   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)\r\nfrom the Immediate
>   window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every
>   CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.\r\n"}
>
> Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this): This
>   exception was thrown because the generator for control
>   'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:28' with name
>   'DeviceListDataGrid' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events
>   that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The
>   following differences were detected:   Accumulated count 27 is
>   different from actual count 28.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last
>   Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]   At index 26: 
>   Generator's item '{NewItemPlaceholder}' is different from actual item
>   'FxEditorDatabaseStructure.Core.Domain.Device'.

Comment: 1) You don't use any `ICollectionView` features. Why do you create it at all? 2) you may call `SaveChanges` when you wan to... well, save changes. E.g., add a button nearby `DataGrid`, and bind it to command, which calls `DbContex.SaveChanges`.

Comment: I plan to utilise the filter features after I get the basics to work. However, the main problem seemed to be the `MessageBox`. Now the `delete` and `Add` functionality is working.. Also I would like to implement add without buttons.

Comment: @ajr tell me if something you don't clear.

Comment: It will be more clear if you can show your `DeviceDatabaseViewModel` class. If something in your code is not as I expected, my answer will not work.

Comment: Great help! Just seems the dataGrid and Device are out of synch which is causing exception

Comment: If you are applying my answer, try remove all `_devices.Remove` and `_devices.Remove` inside `Device_CollectionChanged`. It is not allow to modify the collection why you are looping it items, not the `MessageBox` cause problem.

Comment: [Link to the DeviceViewModel](https://github.com/ajr85/FxTesting/blob/master/FxEditorDatabaseStructure/ViewModel/DeviceDatabaseViewModel.cs) I have disabled all the `add`and `remove` methods, still the same error described above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105296/discussion-between-ajr-and-sakura).

Answer (score 2):

There are serveral thing:

First, you can bind directly to `_devices`, or your top `ObservableCollection` variable, there is no need to have create `DeviceCollectionView`.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceDatabaseViewModel._devices}"
```

Remember to make your `_devices` public access.

Secondly, there is a problem in `Device_CollectionChanged` function, if you apply above change, you can do like this:

```
private bool _isAddedbyApp = false;

private void Device_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.GetType().ToString()); // if not = "Device" then tell me because there something you bind don't correct
                var entity = item as Device;
                if (entity != null && !_isAddedbyApp)
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Add?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        // add entity to database
                        // No need to call _devices.Add() here, you collection
                        // will auto be updated.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // remove this item
                        _devices.Remove(entity);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Third, you still don't know how to use `_isAddedbyApp` variable.

Only use it when your app (not user) add device.

```
_isAddedbyApp = true;   // You start add items.
_context.Add(...);
_isAddedbyApp = false;  // You finished add items.
```

Comment: I do need the `CollectionView`  if I want to later on apply filter functionality for the dataGrid, right?

Comment: If it must be, you should use `ICollectionView cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(o);` instead of `new CollectionViewSource`. In any case don't add/remove item inside `Device_CollectionChanged` or in functions `Device_CollectionChanged` point to. It is hard to tell you detail. If you can compose and send a minimal working project involve your current binding, I can fix it for you myself.

Comment: I tried to create as minimal project about the problema s I could, [here is the link](https://github.com/ajr85/WpfDataGrid.git) Still same error from the message box as in the question.